# Passing KeyVault secrets to .net core 2 xUnit/MsTest in VSTS

Tags: c#, .net, azure-devops, mstest, azure-keyvault

I have several secrets stored in Azure KeyVault. Unfortunately I cannot find a way to pass parameters to my .net Core 2.0 test run via VSTS (Visual Studio Team Services)

Documentation says that Keyvault secrets can only be supplied via VSTS variables - fair enough - but how do I actually do this? All the information I can find on web seems outdated or doesn't work.

For example - consider RunSettings file:

```
<RunSettings>
    <TestRunParameters>  
        <Parameter name="webAppUrl" value="http://localhost" /> 
        <Parameter name="webAppUserName" />
        <Parameter name="webAppPassword" />
  </TestRunParameters> 
</RunSettings>
```

I tried passing values for last 2 parameters via cmd line as follow:

```
vsts.console MyTest.dll /Settings:vsts.runsettings -- -webAppUserName foo
vsts.console MyTest.dll /Settings:vsts.runsettings -- webAppUserName=foo
dotnet test -s vsts.runsettings -- -webAppUserName foo
dotnet test -s vsts.runsettings -- webAppUserName=foo
```

but this has no effect - the webAppUserName value remains null (I can see a value for webAppUrl, so I know my code is right!)

I've also tried both the VSTS "dotnet test" task as well as the "VsTest" task from my VSTS 2017 build. The VsTest provides a **Override test run parameters** setting - and as per the tooltip, I tried:

```
-webAppUserName user -webAppPassword somethingSecret
```

Again - no effect!

Originally I used xUnit and had exactly the same issue - i.e. coudn't figure out a way to pass parameters via VSTS - so I tried MSTest, but same issue.

Going back to my original issue of injecting KeyVault secrets
Locally via VS Studio I was able to just do the following from my test:

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
                ...
                .AddAzureKeyVault(...)
```

Unfortunately, when run via VSTS, the test runner just hangs (i.e. I had to stop it after several minutes) with **no** log output for test step if I use either

**.AddAzureKeyVault(...)** or **.AddEnvironmentVariables()**

So I tried using VSTS Variable Groups - and linking that to KeyVault. However, keyvault secrets are not accessible via environment variables (using Enviroment.GetEnvironmentVariable(...) directly from C#) - so that's no good. They say you can only pass these to tasks via VSTS variables...hence my problem!

**Aside:**
Even if I could use environment variables, it's not optimal because when using .AddAzureKeyVault() I can supply a custom IKeyVaultSecretManager to, for example, replace a special delimiter with the ':' character - this means that I can nest my json config values - e.g. if I had this in my config file:

```
{ "A" : { "B" : "somevalue" } }
```

then using normal configuration builder I can access the above via config["A:B"]. Unfortunately KeyVault doesn't like the ":" character - so you have to replace it with something like "--" and then use a custom IKeyVaultSecretManager to replace "--" with ":" (which works great and ensures that variables are properly overridden based on the order of providers registered in config builder)

Please help! All I wanted for Christmas was not to put my KeyVault secrets into Git... but the VSTS KeyVault grinch is spoiling my fun... surely I'm missing something??

Comment: Find the repository for `AddAzureKeyVault` on Github and review its source to see what it does. Maybe it provides some hints about what you need to make a workaround. This smells like a design issue with tight coupling to dependencies that are difficult to mock/stub/fake for testing.

Comment: @nkosi Thanks for editing/formatting some of the code bits I missed!
The azure key vault code is a bit of a rabbit hole - but essentially it does an https oauth call to authenticate (and I manually set all keys via Env vars, so that's fine). I suspect maybe VSTS is blocking https calls.

In any case - as you should know, we unfortunately live in a world of leaky abstractions - not all problems can be tested by pure unit tests. For now I've used the xUnit Trait attribute to bypass some of my integration tests

Answer (score 3):

Just an update

I've recently set up a new xUnit .NET Core 2.0 project. For this project I had no issues passing environment variables to Azure DevOps. Basically, all you do is:

- Create a Build pipeline variable - e.g. `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`
- Create Visual Studio Test Task
- In your xUnit project, simply use `System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")`

Given that the above works, `.AddEnvironmentVariables()` configuration method should just work fine now aswell. 
This mechanism can be used to load a different config files per test environments too.

For me, this is all I needed as I have a nice easy way to pass environment-specific options to integration tests

Answer (score 0):

The format of overriding test run parameters is like `AppURL=$(DeployURL);Port=8080` instead of `-name value`

[Supplying Run Time Parameters to Tests](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2015/09/04/supplying-run-time-parameters-to-tests/)

Comment: That's one of the many pages I looked at.  Didn't work for me and seems outdated. The -key value  was suggested by vsts vstest tooltip, as oice mentioned above. I suspect maybe this isn't implemented by .net core 2 test adapters yet...

Comment: I assume you are using Visual studio test task 2.* and the override parameter format is -key value, with this task, it will update the runsettings file before running the test, can you get the original value in runsettings file if you do test in local?

Comment: With Visual studio test task 1.*, it works fine with the parameter format like key=value. (Core 2.0 Unit test project)

Comment: Thanks @starianchen-MSFT  Unfortunately the test task 2.* approach didn't work for me - the test keeps on using the original values (which is strange since you say it should replace the values in the source settings file before running the test. 
If I run 'dotnet test /?' locally it certainly seems to indicate that i should add ' --  webAppUserName=foo' as command line parm - but again, it doesn't work!

Comment: What's the result with test task 1.*? (format key=value)

Comment: Unfortunately, this issue is yet to be resolved in .net Core - there are several issues open about this in github [345](https://github.com/Microsoft/testfx/issues/345), [315](https://github.com/Microsoft/testfx/issues/315), [24](https://github.com/Microsoft/testfx/issues/24)
For now, best advice I can give anyone requiring test parameters is to use a .net full framework test - not .net core